# 301 moved permanently with AllowAutoRedirect

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I wrote a class that get the html from a site, this is the code:

```
public class NetworkHelper {
    static Lazy<HttpClient> httpClient = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => {
        var handler = CreateHandler();
        return new HttpClient(handler) {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
        };
    });

    static HttpMessageHandler CreateHandler() {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        // if the framework supports redirect configuration
        // set max redirect to the desired amount the default is 50
        if (handler.SupportsRedirectConfiguration) {
            handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            handler.MaxAutomaticRedirections = 5;
        }
        // if the framework supports automatic decompression 
        // set automatic decompression
        if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression) {
            handler.AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip |
                System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        }
        return handler;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the html structure of a site.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">Represents the URL of the page where to download the data.</param>
    /// <returns>Return a string that contains the html of the site.</returns>
    public async Task<string> GetHtmlAsync(Uri url, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) {
        var response = await httpClient.Value.GetAsync(url, cancellationToken);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return content;
    }
}
```

the problem's that when I try to download the data from this url:

```
string html = await new NetworkHelper().GetHtmlAsync(new Uri("https://int.soccerway.com/charts/statsplus/2139109"));
```

I'll get this content:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://int.soccerway.com/charts/statsplus/2139109/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

so I guess `AllowAutoRedirect` isn't working as expected?

Comment: *GetHtmlAsync* takes a Uri as parameter not a string. Are you sure you've posted the correct code?

Comment: @Eser yep, I fixed the sample

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work (I'ld prefer a `NetworkHelper NetHelper = new NetworkHelper();` declaration at class scope, since you're using a static object initializer, but it wouldn't change the result, here). What framework are you targeting? (As a note, the `Timeout` and `MaxAutomaticRedirections` are way below the default)

Comment: @Jimi I'm using `.NET Standard 2.0` have you tried that?

Comment: I don't have an IDE available right now. What I know is that .NET Core doesn't allow auto redirections if the redirection moves the connections from Https to Http, no matter what `AllowAutoRedirect` says. I'm not sure if that applies to .Net Standard too. I will test it when I can. You could do the same (possibly with .Net framerwork 4.6.1+). I'ld suggest to set higher values for `Timeout` and `MaxAutomaticRedirections` anyway.

Comment: @Charanoglu I am testing this in a unit test and it is executing without any problems. Full HTML document being downloaded. Target framework .Net 4.5.2

Comment: @Nkosi so could be a bug of `.NET Standard 2.0`? How can I report this to `Microsoft`?

Comment: `bug of .NET Standard 2.0?` Don't you think it is too early?

Comment: @Charanoglu debug the code and see if `handler.SupportsRedirectConfiguration` is true for current platform

Comment: Tested now with a ClassLibrary targeting .Net Standard 2.0. The results are as expected. The Html document is downloaded correctly.

Comment: @Nkosi check my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that changing:

```
return new HttpClient(handler) {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
    };
```

to:

```
return new HttpClient(handler) {
            //Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
        };
```

all works well. Seems that there is a limited number of HTTP requests you can do per second, others get queued.

Comment: Then consider increasing the timeout time span.